# Responsive carousel slider controls trigger/fires multiple times when resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I seem to be having an issue with my responsive carousel that I just created. Basically I set the carousel to slide one by one when clicking the `next/prev` button. But when I tried resizing my browser and clicking the `next/prev` button the control seems to trigger multiple times as shown in this screenshot.

I can't seem to figure out why is this happening when resizing.

[image]

```
<div class="faculty-carousel">
    <ul class="faculty-items">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="controls">
        <div class="prev">
        prev
        </div>

        <div class="next">
        next
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fCarousel() {

    // var activeSlide = 0;
    // $('.faculty-carousel').attr('data-slide', '0');


    var viewPortSize        = $(window).width(),
        facultyPanel = $('.faculty-carousel .faculty-items li'),
        profileCount = facultyPanel.length,
        activeSlide         = 0,
        carousel            = $('.faculty-carousel .faculty-items');

    $('.faculty-carousel').attr('data-slide', '0');

    //Set Panel Size based on viewport

    if (viewPortSize <= 1920 ) {
        var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize / 5
    }


    if (viewPortSize < 1024 ) {
        var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize / 4
    }

    if (viewPortSize < 768 ) {
        var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize / 3
    } 

    if (viewPortSize < 480 ) {
        var profilePanelSize = viewPortSize
    }

    carousel.outerWidth( profilePanelSize * profileCount );
    facultyPanel.outerWidth(profilePanelSize);
    carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(' + 0 + '% )');

    $('.prev').on('click', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation();

        var carouselWrapper     = $(this).closest('.faculty-carousel'),
            facultyProfilePanel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items li'),
            facultyProfileCount = facultyProfilePanel.length,
            viewPortSize        = $(window).width(),
            carousel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items'),
            position            = 0,
            currentSlide        = parseInt(carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide'));

        // Check if data-slide attribute is greater than 0
        if (currentSlide > 0) {
            // Decremement current slide
            currentSlide--;
            // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
            var transformPercentage = -1 * currentSlide / facultyProfileCount * 100;
            carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(' + transformPercentage + '% )');

            // Update data-slide attribute
            carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
            activeSlide = currentSlide;
        }

                console.log('prev');
    });

    $('.next').on('click', function(e) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        // store variable relevent to clicked slider

        var carouselWrapper     = $(this).closest('.faculty-carousel'),
            facultyProfilePanel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items li'),
            facultyProfileCount = facultyProfilePanel.length,
            viewPortSize   = $(window).width(),
            carousel = carouselWrapper.find('.faculty-items'),
            position = 0,
            currentSlide = parseInt(carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide'));

        // Check if dataslide is less than the total slides
        if (currentSlide < facultyProfileCount - 1) {
            // Increment current slide
            currentSlide++;
            // Assign CSS position to clicked slider
            var transformPercentage = -1 * currentSlide / facultyProfileCount * 100;
            carousel.css('transform', 'translateX(' + transformPercentage + '% )');

            // Update data-slide attribute
            carouselWrapper.attr('data-slide', currentSlide);
            activeSlide = currentSlide;
        }

        console.log('next');
    })

    $('.faculty-carousel .faculty-items').each(function() {

        // create a simple instance
        // by default, it only adds horizontal recognizers

        var direction,
            touchSlider = this,
            mc = new Hammer.Manager(this),
            itemLength = $(this).find('li').length,
            count = 0,
            slide = $(this),
            timer;

        var sliderWrapper = slide,
            slideItems = sliderWrapper.find('li'),
            //slider = sliderWrapper.find('li'),
            totalPanels = slideItems.length,
            currentSlide = parseInt(sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide'));

        // mc.on("panleft panright", function(ev) {
        //   direction = ev.type;
        // });

        mc.add(new Hammer.Pan({
            threshold: 0,
            pointers: 0
        }))

        mc.on('pan', function(e) {
            var percentage = 100 / totalPanels * e.deltaX / window.innerWidth;
            var transformPercentage = percentage - 100 / totalPanels * activeSlide;
            touchSlider.style.transform = 'translateX( ' + transformPercentage + '% )';
            var sliderWrapper = $(e.target).closest('.faculty-carousel')


            if (e.isFinal) { // NEW: this only runs on event end

                var newSlide = activeSlide;
                if (percentage < 0)
                    newSlide = activeSlide + 1;
                else if (percentage > 0)
                    newSlide = activeSlide - 1;
                goToSlide(newSlide, sliderWrapper);
            }
        });


        var goToSlide = function(number, sliderWrapper) {
            if (number < 0)
                activeSlide = 0;
            else if (number > totalPanels - 1)
                activeSlide = totalPanels - 1
            else
                activeSlide = number;

            sliderWrapper.attr('data-slide', activeSlide);

            touchSlider.classList.add('slide-animation');
            var percentage = -(100 / totalPanels) * activeSlide;
            touchSlider.style.transform = 'translateX( ' + percentage + '% )';
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                touchSlider.classList.remove('slide-animation');
            }, 400);

        };
    });



}

$(document).ready(function() {
    fCarousel();
})

$(window).on('resize', function(){
    fCarousel();
})

</script>
```

---

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

.faculty-items li {
    height : 100px;
}

.faculty-items li:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color : grey;
}

.faculty-items li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color : aqua
}


.faculty-items {
    overflow   : hidden;
    position   : relative;
    right      : 0;
    display : flex;

    -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s linear;
}

.faculty-carousel .controls {
    display : block;
}
```

Comment: Try taking the listeners for prev and next out of fCarousel().

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call fCarousel() you are adding redundant listeners to your prev, next, and whatever else.

You need to move these outside the function.

```
function fCarousel() {
    //I run on resize and update All The Things!
}

$('.prev').on('click', function(e) {
    //I only need to be told my job once
});
$('.next').on('click', function(e) {
    //me too
});
```

Comment: But what if the controls are inside the function instead.

Comment: Do elaborate, exactly which controls ?

Comment: Sorry I meant the event listeners

Comment: That's where they are now, and every time you call fCarousel you duplicate them. So when you do click "prev", it performs the action multiple times, one for each listener you attached to it.

Comment: Edited my answer.